# Relation induced topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, relations

For an ordered space $X$ there is the term of ordered topology generated by sets of the form:

$l(x)=\{ y\in X: y<x\} $ and $r(x)=\{ y\in X: y>x\} $

I was wondering if someone had encountered somewhere and can give a reference of reading materials on an a topology induced by relation. More precisely, for a set $X$ and a binary relation $R$ on $X$, I would call the $R$-induced topology as the topology generated by sets of the form:

$l_R(x)=\{ y\in X: (y,x)\in R \} $ and $r_R(x)=\{ y\in X: (x,y)\in R\} $

Comment: GO (generalized order) spaces might interest you.

Comment: This seems to be a generalization in a different direction. I'm interested  in a partial order relation, since for example it induces (I think) the topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: How is $R^d$ ordered?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a product of linearly ordered spaces, and therefore can be given a partial order of the sort: $(a,b)<(c,d)$ if $a<c$ and $b<d$. This gives us the open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$, which if I am not mistaken generate the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [partially ordered spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_space) are a generalization of [order topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology). I don't directly see how it coincides with your definition, though.

Comment: It does not seem to coincide with my definition.

Comment: If R equivalence relation, then topology is a pairwise disjoint collection of indiscret subspaces.  If R is equality, space is discrete.