# Alternative relation which defines a topology on a finite space

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, relations

I know that given a finite set $X$ and a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on it, we can define a reflexive transitive relation by

$$ x\prec y \quad \text{if} \quad \overline{\{x\} } \subseteq \overline{ \{y\} }. $$

This relation gives the closed subsets of $X$ by

$$  A\text{ closed}\iff\forall a\in A\colon \forall x\in S\colon x\le a\to x\in A, $$

as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285880/421273). By that way, for any reflexive transitive relation $R$ on a finite set we can define a topology from $R$.

I'm trying to determine whether we can define in an alternative method from a relation a topology, in a way that will also yield all topologies. The definition is as follows:

Given a relation $R\subseteq X\times X$, I can define for $x\in X$

$$ \ell_R(x):=\{ y\in X: (y,x) \in R  \} $$
and

$$ r_R(x):=\{y\in X: (x,y)\in R  \}. $$

My topology on $X$ would be the minimal topology containing $\ell_R(x)$ and $r_R(X)$ for all $x\in X$. This construction gives the discrete topology and the trivial topology so I'm not sure where to look for a counter example. I was hoping to reverse engineer a relation $R$ from $\prec$, but hit a mental block so far, and I thought that perhaps there is something basic which I'm overlooking that could help.

I would appreciate any constructive feedback.

Comment: Isn't it the same question as your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057995/relation-induced-topology)?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin It's a simpler version of that previous question, which I thought might be simpler to solve, since that one didn't yield any extensive answers.